# Check whether a property is of type Boolean or not

Tags: .net, vb.net, reflection, types

I am looping over the properties of the current instance using Reflection, and I'm trying to determine if a property is of type `Boolean`. I tried many things (typeof, GetType, etc.) but I'm not getting it working. Here's my code :

```
For Each prop As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo In Me.GetType.GetProperties()
     If prop.PropertyType Is Boolean Then 'Not Compiling
         ' Do Something if boolean
     End If
Next
```

Comment: try `If prop.PropertyType Is GetType(Boolean) Then `

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using the [`GetType` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tay4kywk.aspx) (as opposed to the [`GetType` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)):

```
 If prop.PropertyType Is GetType(Boolean) Then
     ' Do Something if boolean
 End If
```